# Require a file in NodeJS using a canonical or root-relative path

Tags: node.js

I have a fictional utilities package (node module) that I'm importing into my apps like so:

```
var sqrt = require('common-math').sqrt
```

However, using this same module from within the `common-math` module seems to be tricky. I seem to only have to options, both of which are not ideal:

- Use relative path require from every single place I need to get access to the module. This can be `require('../sqrt')` or `require('../../../lib/sqrt')`.
- Put the module in `node_modules/sqrt/index.js` and then do a `require('sqrt')`.

I just want to be able to `require('common-math').sqrt` just like all the consumers of this package do. I realize that I can create a `node_modules/common-math` folder with a symlink to my package's `index.js`, but is this a common/recommended practice?

Comment: Well, actually, you have third option - you may install it globally (to global node_modules). And then you may require it as you wanted.

Comment: And may I ask you, why relative paths are not good enough?

Comment: Because it's very brittle. If I move my consuming file I have a high risk of breaking things. Compare this to Java where I can `import com.common.math.sqrt` from anywhere in my package (or even externally by another package) and you'll see what I mean.

Comment: Global modules isn't the answer here... I'm trying to reference a file in my own package that I'm working on.

Comment: This has been solved elegantly in RequireJS, where you can map a particular directory to a keyword, but apparently not yet in Node.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Node's module loading system is very limited, but what you want is possible. However it is not as elegant as you might expect it to be:

```
var root = (function (p, path) {
        for (; 'common-math' !== path.basename(p); p = path.dirname(p));
        return p;
    }(module.filename, require('path'));

var a = require(root + '/sqrt.js');
```

or even:

```
var root = (function (p) {
        return p.slice(0, p.indexOf('common-math') + 1).join('/');
    }(module.filename.split('/')));

var a = require(root + '/sqrt.js');
```

Comment: Looks like this will work but you'd have to have it in every file that does a require.